# Sending Email with return-path not functioning

Tags: c#, email, return-path

I am using `System.Net.Mail` email. in the code i am setting the return-path of email as follow:

```
string sReturnPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReturnPath"].ToString();
if (sReturnPath.Length > 0) {
    msg.Headers.Add("Return-Path", sReturnPath);
}
```

If the delivery has failed it should go to return-path but it doesn't, even though I can see the header of email's return-path being from config file that I specified. The email gets returned to sender.

any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using a slightly wrong approach. Simple Mail Transfer Protocol ([RFC 2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt)) says:

> A message-originating SMTP system SHOULD NOT send a message that
>   already contains a Return-path header.  SMTP servers performing a
>   relay function MUST NOT inspect the message data, and especially not
>   to the extent needed to determine if Return-path headers are present.

If you want your message to be returned to the address other than the one specified in the `From:` field, then the address should be set in the SMTP message *envelope* rather than in the message *header*. You can achieve this by setting the `Sender` property:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Sender = new MailAddress("not-deliviered@sample.org", "Sam1");
```

Comment: i just noticed something if you send it using sender then the email would say "on behalf of" any solutions for this

Comment: Where exactly would it say "on behalf of"?

Comment: on the from address it says sender@email.com; on behalf of; reciever@email.com... that is when the email is sent successfully

Comment: Well, my guess is that the destination SMTP server adds this string to a message header, I don't think you can do much about it.

Comment: is there any way i can disable this in smtp server? as msg.sender does the bounce back job for me the only problem is the behalf thing...

Comment: What happens is: if there's return path information in a message envelope then SMTP server adds it to the `Sender:` field in a message header upon final delivery to the recipient's mailbox. Some email clients (MS Outlook, for instance) display this information in the UI, some others don't. So the real question is how to get rid of the `Sender:` field. And this entirely depends on a server your recipients are using.

Comment: yea tested this with gmail and outlook apparently gmail doesn't have the 'on behalf'. thanks for your help